# Restrict year value to 4 digit in react js input

Tags: date, input, reactjs

I have below code in my jsx file with react component,

```
  <input
        data-auto={this.props.name}
        name={this.props.name}
        type='date'
        value={this.props.date}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        onKeyUp={this.handleChange}>

 handleChange(e) {
    const eventValue = e.target.value;
 }
```

When I change year value by keyboard, I am able to give digits upto 6. As below,
 [image]

Below are my questions,

When I try to debug it, on key up event, it is going to handleChange function but e.target.value is "",but as per me, it should have value 23231. How it is ""?

I have to restrict the year value to 4 digits only. How to do?

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the year then `type='date'` is the wrong value, as it will require you to enter `day`, `month`, and `year`. Since a `year` consists of `n` digits (in your case 4) we can use `type='number'` and restrict the allowed values to `1000-9999`.

```
const onChange = (e) => {
  console.log("change", e.target.value)
}

const onKeyUp = (e) => {
  console.log("keyUp", e.target.value)
}

const InputExampleInput = () => <input 
  placeholder='Search...'
  type='number'
  min={1000}
  max={9999}
  onChange={onChange}
  onKeyUp={onKeyUp}
  />
```

Using the `up` and `down` arrows on you keyboard the input is restricted to the `min` and `max` values and thus to 4 digits. Since a user is still able to manually enter values outside this range you'll have to do some input validation in the handlers.

I'm not sure why you register a handler for the `KeyUp` event since the `Change` event should already notify you whenever the value changed.